# How do I convert an array of two-dimensional Cartesian coordinates to an OpenCV input array?

Tags: opencv, rust

Initially, I tried implementing the OpenCV [Basic Drawing](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d96/tutorial_basic_geometric_drawing.html) example with rust using [Rust OpenCV bindings](https://github.com/twistedfall/opencv-rust#rust-opencv-bindings) ([Crate opencv 0.48.0](https://docs.rs/opencv)).
However, I was stuck.

I want to draw a closed polygon with [`opencv::imgproc::polylines`](https://docs.rs/opencv/0.48.0/opencv/imgproc/fn.polylines.html).
The vertices of the polygon are given by an array of two-dimensional Cartesian coordinates.
I need to pass these points to the 2nd argument of the function which is of type [`&dyn opencv::core::ToInputArray`](https://docs.rs/opencv/0.48.0/opencv/core/trait.ToInputArray.html).
This is where I struggle. How do I convert the array of vertices to an argument of type `opencv::core::ToInputArray`?

```rust
let pts = [[100, 50], [50, 150], [150, 150]];

imgproc::polylines(
        &mut image, 
        ???, <-- "pts" have to go here   
        true, 
        core::Scalar::from([0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0]), 
        1, 8, 0).unwrap();
```

Minimal example

```rust
use opencv::{core, imgproc, highgui};

fn main() {
    let mut image : core::Mat = core::Mat::new_rows_cols_with_default(
        200, 200, core::CV_8UC4, core::Scalar::from([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])).unwrap();

    // draw yellow quad
    imgproc::rectangle(
        &mut image, core::Rect {x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100},
        core::Scalar::from([0.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0]), -1, 8, 0).unwrap();

    // should draw red triangle -> causes error (of course)
    /*
    let pts = [[100, 50], [50, 150], [150, 150]];
    imgproc::polylines(
        &mut image, 
        &pts, 
        true, 
        core::Scalar::from([0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0]), 
        1, 8, 0).unwrap();
    */

    highgui::imshow("", &image).unwrap();
    highgui::wait_key(0).unwrap();
}
```

```
[dependencies]
opencv = {version = "0.48.0", features = ["buildtime-bindgen"]}
```

Comment: You should be able to do `core::Vector::from(vec![core::Point2i::new(100, 50), ...])` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of the comment from  @kmdreko.

I can define the vertices with an [`opencv::types::VectorOfPoint`](https://docs.rs/opencv/0.48.0/opencv/types/type.VectorOfPoint.html), that implements an [`opencv::core::ToInputArray`](https://docs.rs/opencv/0.48.0/opencv/core/trait.ToInputArray.html) trait:

```rust
let pts = types::VectorOfPoint::from(vec![
    core::Point{x: 100, y: 50},
    core::Point{x: 50, y: 150},
    core::Point{x: 150, y: 150}]
);
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```rust
use opencv::{core, types, imgproc, highgui};

fn main() {
    let mut image : core::Mat = core::Mat::new_rows_cols_with_default(
        200, 200, core::CV_8UC4, core::Scalar::from([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])).unwrap();

    let pts = types::VectorOfPoint::from(vec![
        core::Point{x: 100, y: 50},
        core::Point{x: 50, y: 150},
        core::Point{x: 150, y: 150}]
    );

    imgproc::polylines(
        &mut image, 
        &pts, 
        true, 
        core::Scalar::from([0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0]), 
        1, 8, 0).unwrap();
    
    highgui::imshow("", &image).unwrap();
    highgui::wait_key(0).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Cool - well done. And thanks for sharing back.

Comment: In the end, using OpenCV in rust works flawlessly